# Switching to landscape, auto constraints in wrong corner

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, interface-builder

I'm presenting a view controller when my view controller is rotated to horizontal.

In my NIb, I have a help button with constraints to margin top and right of 8 pixels each. However, my view controller displays with the button in the top right of a Portait perspective. See image. How do I make this show up in top right in Landscape?

[image]

Comment: Your interface did not rotate. Look at the status bar. This isn't auto-layout it's an issue with your supported orientations.

Comment: @Dare , thanks. It turns out there were duplicate PLIST entries with the same key and the latter lacked the Landscape values!

Comment: @Dare you can put an answer for this if you like

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your screen did not rotate, because the status bar is still in portrait mode. BUT... even if it did rotate, you would probably have problems because the status bar is 8 pts wide, and it is automatically removed in landscape mode.

I'd say (1) set your constraints to put the button 30 or 40 pts from the corner, until you get the rotation stuff worked out, and (2) fix the rotation issues by looking at the settings for which rotations the simulator supports. Normally rotations allowed by xcode (at least for my default swift projects) are left, portrait, landscape, but not upside down.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me all the time, when using the simulator!

(Assuming that your project is supporting both landscape and portrait mode)
To make sure your device has rotated from landscape to portrait or the other way around, simply rotate it three times instead of once! (Press the ⌘ and then → three times)

Also for your button placement, I would recommend creating a Standard offset to superview's top and trailing margins, without using any particular numbers (Standard pops up when you delete the number in the constraint's Attribute Inspector).